# Как добавить список в sql запрос

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

Имеется sql запрос, который я отправляю в бд, но проблема заключается в том, что я не могу добавить список в фильтр, подскажите как можно решить данную проблему.

```
    if cursor is not None:
        sql = f"""
        SELECT
            id_users,
            date,
            info,
            actions
        FROM
            name_table
        WHERE `id_task` IN '{list_values}'

        """
        cursor.execute(sql)
        response_db = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id_task, '{CSV_list_values}')`. Причём CSV - без паразитных пробелов после запятой.

Comment: @Akina, Если указывать приставку CSV_ внутри {} питон будет ругаться на не известную переменную, если выставить эту приставку вот так CSV_'{list_values}' - выдается ошибка (pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1583, "Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'FIND_IN_SET'")), если ее вовсе убрать - возвращается пустой запрос.

Comment: Можно преобразовать list в tuple. Тогда ругаться не будет. Тут еще момент, так переменные в запрос лучше не передавать. Почитайте об sql-инъекциях и способах решения.

Comment: Не мудри. В переменной/параметре `{CSV_list_values}` должно быть нечто типа `123,456,789`. И соответственно текст запроса будет `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id_task, '123,456,789')`.

Comment: @Akina, разобрался, `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id_task, '123,456,789')` к такому виду привел, все работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ содержится в комментариях, я лишь дополню.
Перед тем как подать список в запрос его необходимо перевести в строку, а точнее преобразовать к такому виду `'1,2,3,4'`, а после вставить уже в сам запрос `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id_task, '1,2,3,4')`

Comment: сам ответ лучше было сразу и привести. [edit]